# Java jib-maven-plugin with Kubernetes memory controll

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, java-11, jib

Actually I'm using the **jib-maven-plugin** to create Docker container for my application. Then I'm going to deploy it to Google servers where we have a **Kubernetes** environment.

Actually we are playing with the java env. variables from the **jib-maven-plugin**'s config (**pom.xml**):

```
<jvmFlags>
  <jvmFlag>-XX:MinRAMPercentage=60.0</jvmFlag>
  <jvmFlag>-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0</jvmFlag>
  <jvmFlag>-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError</jvmFlag>
  <jvmFlag>-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"</jvmFlag>
</jvmFlags>
```

Now we would like to move these configurations to our **deployment yml** file, we found something like:

```
env:
- name: JAVA_OPTS
  value: "-XX:MinRAMPercentage=60.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90.0 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
...
resources: 
    limits:
        memory: 512Mi
    requests:
        memory: 256Mi
```

but it seems that if we remove these configs from the jib-maven-plugin's config file and move them to the yml file they are simply not working. The container starts without having any effects of the mentioned settings.

We are using open JDK 11, that may be also important.

How it's possible to control the Java env. options from the deployment file?

Thank you so much for your help, have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `JAVA_OPTS` and not `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`.
`JAVA_OPTS` is used by some application servers like Tomcat, but [the JDK itself uses JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE).

Therefore, a working Kubernetes yaml would be something like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    ...
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
        ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ...
          image: ...
          env:
            - name: JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS
              value: -XX:MinRAMPercentage=60 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

Comment: Hello, it seems that it's working based on some tests, but after I added the mentioned configuration a new ERROR log appeared into the logs: "NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:MinRAMPercentage=40.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.0" Do you know something about this ?

Comment: Based on a research it seems that this is totally "normal". "it's a feature and not a bug" ... This is logged by the JDK. To be honest I dont know why is it an error ...

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a bit to the other answer.

For those using Java 9+ (as with OP), both `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` and `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` (beware it's neither `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS`, `JAVA_TOOL_OPTS`, nor `JAVA_OPTS`) will likely work in this use case to prepend options at runtime.

For those using Java 8, only `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` will work.

Answer (score -1):

Move your jvm parameters to config map and initialize your pod from it by reading it as an env variables. Here is an example how you can achieve it

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data